# What unicode ranges are considered letters?

Tags: unicode

I'm trying to do some text processing. I could easily write a regex for the languages I know (`A-Z` for english), but adding in what counts as a letter in hebrew, arabic, chinese etc. is too much.

What character ranges does unicode think are letters?

Answer (score 5):

As well as being categorized by their range, every Unicode character has something called a 'general category'. You probably want to use the following categories:

```
[Lu]    Letter, Uppercase
[Ll]    Letter, Lowercase
[Lt]    Letter, Titlecase
[Lm]    Letter, Modifier
[Lo]    Letter, Other
```

This excludes numbers, punctuation, symbols and so on (it's the same set as Java's `Character.isLetter` uses). If your regex engine supports it, you can check if an input character is inside one of these categories  with `\p{L}`.

The entire list of categories is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category), and [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property) has more information on the `\p` regex syntax.

Comment: It's worth noting that characters can only belong to *one* category, so characters with multiple uses like `Ⅿ`, `Ⓟ`, and some Asian letter marks are classified as "alphabetic" characters but are not in the "letter" categories.

Comment: @一二三 That's true, there is a difference. To add another example, ↈ (ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED THOUSAND) is listed as alphabetic but not as a letter - I'd say that's a number and not a letter, so I'd use the category, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to look at this: [Unicode Character Ranges](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php) which contains the range for the languages. Specifically there is no general range, it varies for different language like for Arabic it is 0600 — 06FF, for hebrew it is 0590 — 05FF etc.

Answer (score 0):

### **Short Answer**:

- If you target `UTF-16` **Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)** : You have **380** ranges.
- If you target `UTF-16` with **Supplementary code points**: You have **648** ranges.

### **Long Answer:**

(Jump to code section directly if you want to bypass this explanation).

If we consider `UTF-16` **Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)**, the [code points](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) range from `0x0000` to `0xFFFF` which means a number of **65536** code points. The ones supported by `Char` type in languages such as `Java` or `C#`.

Besides BMP, other planes (16 actually) are supported by Unicode to support other characters (Not well known languages, emojis ...etc.) that range from `0x10000` to `0x10FFFF` using 21 bits, which is basically not possible using the two bytes of `UTF-16`. This is achieved using `Surrogates`, a couple of code points (a lower and higher) within the range of BMP that will help us find the character that cannot be represented by BMP, the lower and the higher surrogates are used in a special formula to determine the targeted character. More details and better explanation in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction).

Let's translate all this to a language vocabulary such as `C#`'s:

A `BMP` Character is represented by the type `Char` that can represent **65536** characters.

To represent the other planes' characters, we may use `char.ConvertFromUtf32(n)` (such as n is between `0x000000` and `0x00D7FF` and between `0x00E000` and `0x10FFFF` inclusively, the interval [`0x00D800`, `0x00DFFF`] is dedicated to surrogates).
A better alternative is the [`Rune`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-7.0) type. `Rune` is similar to [`Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-7.0) but supports what `Char` can't, which means the other planes' code points.

A Rune "character" that is not part of the `Char` range is calculated using surrogates as I mentioned before. In other terms a `Rune` can be represented by 2 `Char` instances at most, see [Rune.EncodeToUtf16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune.encodetoutf16) and [Rune.Utf16SequenceLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune.utf16sequencelength).

**What are the ranges for characters that are considered letters ?**

Both `Char` and `Rune` have the capabilities to tell us if a "character" is a letter or not since they both provide their respective `IsLetter()` methods.

A simple solution would be to iterate through `Char`'s range and apply the Char.IsLetter method, and likewise for `Rune`. Two methods will result:

1. The first method `CharLettersRanges` to get letters ranges from **0** to **65535** inclusively.

   ```
   public IEnumerable<(ulong from, ulong to)> CharLettersRanges()
   {
       var ranges = new List<(ulong from, ulong to)>();

       char c = default(char);
       var isLetter = false;

       ulong start = 0;
       ulong end = 0x00FFFF; // 65_535;
       var range = default((ulong from, ulong to));

       for (ulong i = start; i <= end; i++)
       {
           c = (char)i;
           if (char.IsLetter(c))
           {
               if (!isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = true;
                   range.from = i;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if (isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = false;
                   range.to = i - 1;
                   ranges.Add(range);
               }
           }
       }

       return ranges;
   }
   ```
2. The second method `RuneLettersRanges` to find ranges beyond [**0, 65535**] (by avoiding surrogates range of course), which means from **0** to **55,295** and from **57,344** to **1,114,111**. (Note that not necessarily all these code points represent actual characters, many of them haven't been attributed yet).

   ```
   public IEnumerable<(ulong from, ulong to)> RuneLettersRanges()
   {
       var ranges = new List<(ulong from, ulong to)>();

       Rune c = default(Rune);
       var isLetter = false;
       var range = default((ulong from, ulong to));

       ulong start = 0;
       ulong end = 0xD7FF; //55_295;

       for (ulong i = start; i <= end; i++)
       {
           c = (Rune)i;
           if (Rune.IsLetter(c))
           {
               if (!isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = true;
                   range.from = i;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if (isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = false;
                   range.to = i - 1;
                   ranges.Add(range);
               }
           }
       }

       //Avoiding surrogates between 0xD800 and 0xDFFF

       start = 0xE000; //57_344
       end = 0x10FFFF; //1_114_111;

       for (ulong i = start; i <= end; i++)
       {
           c = (Rune)i;
           if (Rune.IsLetter(c))
           {
               if (!isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = true;
                   range.from = i;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if (isLetter)
               {
                   isLetter = false;
                   range.to = i - 1;
                   ranges.Add(range);
               }
           }
       }

       return ranges;
   }
   ```

The first method `CharLettersRanges` Will return **380** ranges while the second method `RuneLettersRanges` will return **648** ranges.

If you had to chose one method, you can safely consider the bigger capacity characters `Rune` as the `Char`'s 380 ranges are included in the 648 ranges of `Rune`.

For fun, you can calculate how much letters are there "until now" in the Unicode system, by summing the lengths of the ranges, which will give you **131756 letters**.